# Setting maximum autoscale provisioned throughput for cosmos db

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm doing cost analysis for a cosmos db project. I used the cosmos db capacity calculator for cost estimation. In the capacity calculator, I added storage as `1000GB` and it gave me `EST. STORAGE COST PER MONTH` amount and based on workload details, the capacity calculator gave `3,973RU/s` as `EST. THROUGHPUT REQUIRED` for transactional workload and `EST. WORKLOAD COST/MONTH` amount. While creating the container, I  put `3,973RU/s` as estimated by the cosmos capacity calculator itself.

But as the storage grew from ~400GB to more, provisioned throughput also increased automatically to `5000RU/s` and higher as storage continued to increase thus increasing the total cost.

Reading a Microsoft Azure article, I understood that `max(400,10*(total storage), another factor not important here)` should be minimum provisioned throughput.

1. What should I keep as provisioned throughput? `3,973RU/s`(estimated by capacity calculator) or `10,000RU/s`?
2. Shouldn't the calculator show `10,000RU/s` as the required min? throughput considering I entered `1000GB` as total storage?

I could have set the correct throughput while creating the container. Want to understand why the fact that throughput is directly dependent on storage is not considered by the capacity calculator while estimating the total throughput(`RU/s`) and only considered for storage cost? Since I'm new to Azure & ComosDB, would like to know if I'm missing any information.

[image]

Comment: The `storage in GB * 10 RU/s` applies to autoscale and not manual throughput (so essentially a range between 1000-10,000RU/s for 1000GB). For manual throughput it's `storage in GB * 1 RU/s` as minimum. Unsure what you mean with 'as the storage grew'. Did you try a real scenario? Does the calculator say that? Where did you try that?

Comment: I'm using autoscale option. Storage increased from initial 400GB to 500gb and so on to 1000gb. Initially at 400gb, throughput was set as what I had mentioned while creating the container. But as the size of container increase, min. throughput automatically increased too basis GB*10RU/s. It's real scenario happening for one of the cosmos db PoC.

Answer (score 1):

The calculator does not seem to take the minimum RU/s from storage into account. For the autoscale option that should be indeed be `storage in GB * 10 RU/s`. For your cost calculation you should into account that your RU can range from 1000-10,000 RU and is calculated on a per hour basis based on your max RU usage. So if you estimate ~4000 RU average for that you'll pay 40% of the max throughput.

I would suggest using the Cosmos Calculator to estimate the size and an estimate of the total RU usage from CRUD operations, but for cost it's better to use the [Azure Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/). It's more up to date and also takes into account new features. Autoscale for example costs more per RU than manual throughput, which is not shown in the Cosmos Calculator.

Then there's some more considerations to take into account such as the minimum RU you'll be able to set (based on the formula you found) and RU being split across partitions, which is especially important if you have 'hot' partitions (partitions doing significantly more work than others).

The best indicator is just trying it and observing the cost & metrics. Depending on your use case it might even be better to move to manual throughput where you have the option to set RU as low as 1000 RU/s. Well below your anticipated usage.